# I Have a Segmented control with segments 0,1,2,3,4 but I want to sort them in descending order in the same UISegmentControl

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I Have a `UISegmentedControl` with segments 0,1,2,3,4 but I want to sort them in descending order in the same `UISegmentedControl`.

Comment: can you show soem code

Comment: The requirement is like get the integer values from a uitextfiled and needto store in UISegmentedControl ascending order  Please help

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: Thanks for reply  the requirement is when we enter the integer values to a UITEXTFiled one by one, we should load that values to a UISegmentedControl in ascending Order Could you please suggest how to proceed I am able to set values to a segmented control but unable to sort them in ascending order pls suggest.

Comment: can you show ur code

Answer (score 1):

If you got the segment values in an array then you can sort it easily. for example consider the following

```
let arrayOfIntsAsStrings = ["103", "2", "1", "50", "55", "98"]

let sortedArray = sorted(arrayOfIntsAsStrings, {
    (str1: String, str2: String) -> Bool in
    return str1.toInt() < str2.toInt()
})
```

Then you can print the sorted array

Comment: Reference [link](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/08/16/sort-yourself-out-sorting-an-array-in-swift/)